# Is there such a thing as the "Babushka Bomb" (i.e. Eastern European women age quickly in appearance)?

Tags: europe, aging, beauty

On the internet, there are a [lot of references](https://www.google.com/search?q=babushka%20bomb) to the so-called "Babushka bomb", 
which is defined at [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=babushka%20bomb) as

> Eastern European women are pretty when they're young, but age quickly and badly. The babushka bomb hits.

Are there any studies that have looked into this, for example, by comparing photos side by side of Eastern European and Western women, for different age groups?

Comment: Urban Dictionary is the notable claim here?

Comment: That was an edit made by @Oddthinking, not by me (defending myself in case you were the guy who down-voted, lol:).

Comment: Urban Dictionary is (a) a step up from the original Google Search, which changes daily, varies between people and contains a lot of unrelated links and (b) used the exact word choice of the OP, suggesting a common origin.